# Import requests working on Windows shell but not in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

The simple import of requests

```
import requests
```

can be executes and used in windows shell but the same code says in pycharm:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/XPS13/PycharmProjects/Testing/Webcrawler_Test.py", line 1, in 
<module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

requests was correctly pip installed. Even uninstalling and reinstalling doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try: `print(requests)`, just after importing it (on the shell that works). Most likely, you're launching different interpreters.

Comment: Do you have different version of python?

Comment: `print(requests)` gives me on shell:
<module 'requests' from 'C:\\Users\\XPS13\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages\\requests\\__init__.py'>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [configure the project interpreter in PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html):

- Go to **Settings/Preferences**
- Select **Project Interpreter**
- Click the little gear and click **Add...**
- Select the appropriate interpreter (whether a virtual environment or system python installation)

Comment: I had an issue when trying it first. I really don't know what is was but now it is working when set up the right interpreter. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah so this might be a little late but I fixed my problem like this:

- Go to **Settings/Preferences**
- Select **Project Interpreter**
- And press the **+ button** on the left side

[That + sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pL2BW.png)

- Search for **requests**
- And press **Install Package**

I am running:
Windows 10
Python 3.7.1

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Settings top right
2. '+' above Package table
3. Search: Requests & highlight in list
4. Install Package

[image]